# C# - writing bit by bit into binary file

Tags: c#, binaryfiles

This is a piece of code that aim to make use of Shannon coding on .txt file. What I hope to accomplish here is to create binary file that stores encoded message.

An array **codes** stores strings with only 0s and 1s. (codes)

An array **symbolsSet** contains characters in the form of integer values.

**indexFirstProbability** is just the value that indicates where we need to start reading symbolSet.

**sampleText** is a string we want to encode (Shannon codes were made based on it)

My code produces wrong output. Instead of writing one bit at time into a file, it writes two bits where first one is always 0.

For example if code for letter a is 00 and for b is 110, the output file  for message aab is: **00 00 00 00 01 01 00** instead of  **0 0 0 0 1 1 0** (spaced added for readability).

I would appreciate if someone explain to me why my code works that way and how to fix it.

```
static void saveMessageIntoBinaryFile (string[] codes, int[] symbolSet, 
            int indexFirstProbability, string sampleText, string fileName, string path)
{
    BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(File.Open( path + fileName + ".bin", FileMode.Create));

    string temp;
    bool oneOrZero;

    foreach (char s in sampleText)
    {
        temp = codes[Array.IndexOf(symbolSet, s) - indexFirstProbability];

        foreach (char b in temp)
        {
            if (b == '0')
                oneOrZero = false;
            else  
                oneOrZero = true;

            binaryWriter.Write(oneOrZero);
        }

    }
    binaryWriter.Close();
}
```

Comment: You do realise that BinaryWriter.Write takes a byte?  A byte has eight bits...  So your implementation is using a whole byte to represent a bit. i.e. wasting 7 bits

Comment: `BinaryWriter.Write(bool)` does indeed only write one byte; not two.  Are you sure you're not misreading a hex dump?  In usual hex editor notation, `01` indicates a single byte with value 1.

Comment: @KiwiPiet I wasn't aware of that. I want to write this file bit by bit. I also cofused names "bit" and "byte" while writing this post...

Comment: @user5090812 It is possible - my first encounter with reading binary files was today and I'm using Visual Studio to do it.

Comment: @user5090812 It not the case. I've wrote a decoder - and it decodes the file as if it really contained additional 0s.

Answer (score 0):

I would do sth like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    SaveMessageIntoBinaryFile(new []{"00", "110"}, new char[]{'a', 'b'}, "aab", "output.txt", "");
}

static void SaveMessageIntoBinaryFile (string[] codes, char[] symbolSet, string sampleText, string fileName, string path)
{
    using(var writer = new StreamWriter(File.Open(Path.Combine(path, fileName), FileMode.Create)))
    {
        foreach(var symbol in sampleText)
        {
            var codeIndex = Array.IndexOf<char>(symbolSet, symbol);
            writer.Write(codes[codeIndex]);
            Console.Write(codes[codeIndex] + "\t");
        }
    }
}
```

You can try to launch it here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jj27Fu

Do you really need binary output?

Comment: The whole point of encoding .txt file is to compress it, so I need binary output.

Comment: Then the smallest unit you can operate on is byte. Refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648651/how-to-write-bits-to-a-file